# How to redirect an XPage user to another page via Java

Tags: java, xpages

Inside XPages I'm using some controller classes to bind the XPages's beforePageLoad() event to a Java Method.

In this method I want to redirect the user to a different web page.  It works.. BUT it throws a ton of errors on the console.

```
public void beforePageLoad() throws Exception {

        Map<String, String> param = (Map<String, String>) XSPUtil.resolveVariable("param");
        if (!param.containsKey("exhibitorId")) {
            System.out.println("Redirecting");
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ExternalContext externalContext = fc.getExternalContext();

            XSPContext context = XSPContext.getXSPContext(fc);
            context.redirectToPage("/test.xsp");
}
```

That's the basic code..  I've tried with the externalContext... this sample is showing the XSPContext.  So I'm just not sure how to do it.

The binding to an event isn't a problem.  That's working great.  It's just using the event in Java to redirect to another page.
Some of the messages I'm getting are:

2/9/15 1:06 PM: Exception Thrown
Context Path: /coms/exhibitor.nsf
Page Name: /home.xsp
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: com.ibm.xsp.acl.RedirectSignal
    at com.sun.faces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.initBeforeContents(UIViewRootEx.java:1621)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:333)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createViewRoot(AbstractCompiledPage.java:167)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:521)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    at frostillicus.controller.ControllingViewHandler.createView(ControllingViewHandler.java:89)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:251)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at org.openntf.domino.xsp.adapter.OpenntfHttpService.doService(OpenntfHttpService.java:86)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.acl.RedirectSignal
    at com.ibm.xsp.designer.context.XSPContext.renderPage(XSPContext.java:194)
    at com.ibm.xsp.designer.context.XSPContext.redirectToPage(XSPContext.java:917)
    at com.ibm.xsp.designer.context.XSPContext.redirectToPage(XSPContext.java:929)
    at controller.home.beforePageLoad(home.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.sun.faces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:138)

Answer (score 7):

This is not an error. Just an exception to notify other processes. Normally, SSJS processor uses this to stop further processing of the code.

You might ignore that:

```
try {
    context.redirectToPage("/test.xsp");
} catch (RedirectSignal rs) {
    // Ignoring this error. Useless!
}
```

Comment: Hmm have to try this as I use this sometimes... Thanks Serdar!

Comment: Worked great! Thank you!!  I should note that you need to add an import for this: import com.ibm.xsp.acl.RedirectSignal;